# video with 100% width on a widescreen

Tags: html, css, video, width

When I set my html5 video width and height to 100%, the video height is bigger than the browser visible area and a vertical scrollbar appears.

Is it because my video is in 4:3 format? How can I resize it to fill the entire space without having to scroll down the page?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Possible duplicate to this [posting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4000818/scale-html5-video-and-break-aspect-ratio-to-fill-whole-site)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to check the browser window height with javascript and limit your video to be smaller than that. Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xS3j8/1/) 
HTML:

```
<video id="vid1" controls>
    <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
      <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

CSS:

```
video {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Javascript:

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
  var h=window.innerHeight;  
  document.getElementById("vid1").style.maxHeight=h+"px";  
}
```

Comment: I added this code but it doesn't do what I'm trying to accomplish, it just changes when I resize the browser. I want the video to fit the browser 100% horizontally and vertically when the page loads. Thanks anyway.